# Rotating an animation does not work after changing X,Y of an Image

Tags: android

I need to locate a click on one ImageView (image1) and then to set my second ImageView (image2) to the same position, and start a rotate animation on image2.

My animatiom works fine when i don't change image2 position.

When I want to change the position and start the animation together image2 is moving all over the screen.

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="-50"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1000"
    />
</set>
```

My java code is:

```
 image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            image2.setX(image1.getX());
            image2.setY(image1.getY());
            Animation animation = 
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.myanim);
            image2.startAnimation(animation);
           }
    });
```

Comment: what happens if you call `image2.invalidate();` after setting the x and y values and before starting the animation?

Comment: the same, image2 is still moving on the screen.